# modifiy item property in list(of structure)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-2.0, generic-list

In a list(of structure), i constantly have to modifiy the property of items using this code

```
Private Sub ChangeState(ByVal ww As WebWorker, _
                        ByVal NewState As WorkerState)
        Dim oWBB As WebWorker = ListWebWorkers.Find(Function(item As WebWorker) item.Browser.Name.ToLower = ww.Browser.Name.ToLower)
        If oWBB.Browser IsNot Nothing Then
            ListWebWorkers.Remove(oWBB)
            oWBB = ww
            oWBB.State = NewState
            ListWebWorkers.Add(oWBB)
        End If
    End Sub
```

But this give problem when two or more of the items call this sub procedure. in that one item may already have been removed. This code is executed in the ui thread, and has to be

so is there a better way to modify the items in list structure?

thanks

Comment: Why is WebWorker a Structure and not a Class?

Comment: @Meta-Knight what is the difference when in a class, and what would be the advantage?

Comment: If WebWorker was a class, you wouldn't need to remove and then add the item again. The best practice is to almost always use a Class, unless you have an immutable data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you are not checking the correct item for existence (you are checking `oWBB.Browser`, but you should be checking `oWBB`. In addition, it is not thread-safe.

It would be easier to verify the items existence in a threadsafe manner if you used a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead.

Here's an example of the rewritten code:

```
' Create a dictionary with case-insensitive keys
Private Shared ListWebWorkers As New System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, WebWorker)(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

Private Sub ChangeState(ByVal ww As WebWorker, ByVal NewState As WorkerState)

    If ListWebWorkers.ContainsKey(ww.Browser.Name) Then
        ListWebWorkers.TryRemove(ww.Browser.Name)
        ww.State = NewState
        ListWebWorkers.TryAdd(ww.Browser.Name, ww)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to lock the resources that are not thread safe. This ensures that only one thread is accessing them at a given time.

```
Private Sub ChangeState(ByVal ww As WebWorker, _ 
                    ByVal NewState As WorkerState) 

    SyncLock ListWebWorkers
        Dim oWBB As WebWorker = ListWebWorkers.Find(Function(item As WebWorker) item.Browser.Name.ToLower = ww.Browser.Name.ToLower) 
        If oWBB.Browser IsNot Nothing Then 
            ListWebWorkers.Remove(oWBB) 
            oWBB = ww 
            oWBB.State = NewState 
            ListWebWorkers.Add(oWBB) 
        End If 
    End SyncLock 
End Sub
```

Comment: The app is not multithreaded, but am using multiple webbrowsers to do some work. does this apply here

Comment: If the app is not multithreaded, how can it be that an item is removed twice?